# How to change Google translate default language in search results?

Tags: google-search

When I google "translate", it brings up a little mini-translation app at the top of the search results. Frustratingly, though, for some reason it defaults to Hindi->English, which is not something I need or can recall ever having needed. I cannot find settings for this anywhere. This is not the case for translate.google.com, only the one in the search results.

How can I change this?

Comment: I guess that is browser issue. Clear the cache and then test it.

Answer (score 1):

- check **Region Settings** - **https://www.google.com/preferences?fg=1**
- check **Language Settings** - **[https://www.google.com/preferences?fg=1#lang](https://www.google.com/preferences?hl=en-EN&fg=1#languages)**
- delete cookies: **<kbd>CTRL</kbd>** + **<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>** + **<kbd>DELETE</kbd>**